# How to start with phonegap development?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cross-platform, cordova

Hi I have gone throught the site: [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com)

I have also read the documentation provided there, but is there any easy way tutorial available for that?

I have less idea about javascript coding and what I found is phonegap is entirely based on javascript. Can anyone guide me from where to start with?

Thanks in advance.

Mrunal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - http://docs.phonegap.com/ : This will give you the insight of
>     PhoneGap APIs with source:
> - http://drupal.org/project/phonegap : Here you will get the complete
>     source code of Drupal PhoneGap app which runs of Android. iPhone and
>     BlackBerry. This source will help you to understand the PhoneGap
>     development techniques

Answer (score 2):

they do have detailed set-up instructions and gettin started help.

You don't need JavaScript for a basic Phonegap App. What they do is basically translate a WebPage to a App for the desired Plattform. Therefore you just need to know as much Javascript as your app needs.

Afaik you can also use frameworks like jQuery.
More tutorials are available here: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials

Here on UI Development: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36767911/UI%20Development%20on%20PhoneGap

And there is many more.
Maybe you can look into general Javascript tutorials first if you look for a special effect or so.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006X4A1TM) has more books on PhoneGap that offers basic tutorials and code walkthroughs.  Here is a [new book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006X4A1TM) with sample code available for download.